# "He can do it by himself."

Tags: prepositions, spoken-english

Is using "by" before a reflexive pronoun at the end of a sentence optional?

Contrastive examples:

- He can do it by himself.
- He can do it himself.

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight difference in possible meaning.

*He can do it himself* emphasises *he*. It could be written (in rather formal language) as *He himself can do it.*

*He can do it by himself* means *on his own, without help.*

Of course in everyday speech the first often means the same as the second, for example when speaking of a child learning to dress himself.